# Add a new view to fullcalendar v 2.1.1

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to add a new month view to fullcalendar where all the day are in column (like a timeline).

Is there a way to do that properly and remain compatible with the original plugin ?

Comment: Post your codes for this...

Comment: There's an [Year View implementation](https://github.com/tpruvot/fullcalendar), but I have no idea how to install that easily or how does it work.

Answer (score 3):

### Update

Note that fullcalendar now has another system for handling third party views and plugins.

How I do it now:

```
(function() {
    'strict';


    var FC = $.fullCalendar, // a reference to FullCalendar's root namespace
        View = FC.View, // the class that all views must inherit from
        ListView; // our subclass

    ListView = View.extend({ // make a subclass of View

        computeRange: function(date) {
            var intervalDuration = moment.duration(this.opt('duration') || this.constructor.duration || {
                days: 10
            });
            var intervalUnit = 'day';
            var intervalStart = date.clone().startOf(intervalUnit);
            var intervalEnd = intervalStart.clone().add(intervalDuration);
            var start, end;

            // normalize the range's time-ambiguity
            intervalStart.stripTime();
            intervalEnd.stripTime();

            start = intervalStart.clone();
            start = this.skipHiddenDays(start);
            end = intervalEnd.clone();
            end = this.skipHiddenDays(end, -1, true); // exclusively move backwards

            return {
                intervalDuration: intervalDuration,
                intervalUnit: intervalUnit,
                intervalStart: intervalStart,
                intervalEnd: intervalEnd,
                start: start,
                end: end
            };
        },

        initialize: function() {
            // called once when the view is instantiated, when the user switches to the view.
            // initialize member variables or do other setup tasks.

            View.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        },

        render: function() {

            // responsible for displaying the skeleton of the view within the already-defined
            // this.el, a jQuery element.
            View.prototype.render.apply(this, arguments);
        },

        computeTitle: function() {
            return moment().format(this.opt('titleFormat'));
        },

        setHeight: function(height, isAuto) {
            // responsible for adjusting the pixel-height of the view. if isAuto is true, the
            // view may be its natural height, and `height` becomes merely a suggestion.
            this.el.height(height);

            View.prototype.setHeight.apply(this, arguments);
        },

        renderEvents: function(events) {
            // reponsible for rendering the given Event Objects

            var noDebug = true;
            noDebug || console.log(events);

            var eventsCopy = events.slice().reverse(); //copy and reverse so we can modify while looping

            var tbody = $('<tbody></tbody>');

            this.scrollerEl = this.el.addClass('fc-scroller');

            this.el.html('')
                .append('<table style="border: 0; width:100%"></table>').children()
                .append(tbody);

            var periodEnd = this.end.clone(); //clone so as to not accidentally modify

            noDebug || console.log('Period start: ' + this.start.format("YYYY MM DD HH:mm:ss Z") + ', and end: ' + this.end.format("YYYY MM DD HH:mm:ss Z"));

            var currentDayStart = this.start.clone();
            while (currentDayStart.isBefore(periodEnd)) {

                var didAddDayHeader = false;
                var currentDayEnd = currentDayStart.clone().add(1, 'days');

                noDebug || console.log('=== this day start: ' + currentDayStart.format("YYYY MM DD HH:mm:ss Z") + ', and end: ' + currentDayEnd.format("YYYY MM DD HH:mm:ss Z"));

                //Assume events were ordered descending originally (notice we reversed them)
                for (var i = eventsCopy.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                    var e = eventsCopy[i];

                    var eventStart = e.start.clone();
                    var eventEnd = this.calendar.getEventEnd(e);

                    if (!noDebug) {
                        console.log(e.title);
                        console.log('event index: ' + (events.length - i - 1) + ', and in copy: ' + i);
                        console.log('event start: ' + eventStart.format("YYYY MM DD HH:mm:ss Z"));
                        console.log('event end: ' + this.calendar.getEventEnd(e).format("YYYY MM DD HH:mm:ss Z"));
                        console.log('currentDayEnd: ' + currentDayEnd.format("YYYY MM DD HH:mm:ss Z"));
                        console.log(currentDayEnd.isAfter(eventStart));
                    }

                    if (currentDayStart.isAfter(eventEnd) || (currentDayStart.isSame(eventEnd) && !eventStart.isSame(eventEnd)) || periodEnd.isBefore(eventStart)) {
                        eventsCopy.splice(i, 1);
                        noDebug || console.log("--- Removed the above event");
                    } else if (currentDayEnd.isAfter(eventStart)) {
                        //We found an event to display

                        noDebug || console.log("+++ We added the above event");

                        if (!didAddDayHeader) {
                            tbody.append('\
                                <tr class="fc-header" date="">\
                                    <th colspan="2">\
                                        <span class="fc-header-day">' + currentDayStart.format('dddd') + '</span>\
                                        <span class="fc-header-date">' + currentDayStart.format(this.opt('columnFormat')) + '</span>\
                                    </th>\
                                </tr>');

                            didAddDayHeader = true;
                        }

                        /*
                        <td class="fc-event-handle">\
                                <span class="fc-event"></span>\
                            </td>\
                         */

                        var segEl = $('\
                        <tr class="fc-row fc-event-container fc-content">\
                            <td class="fc-time">' + (e.allDay ? this.opt('allDayText') : e.start.format('H:mm') + '-' + e.end.format('H:mm')) + '</td>\
                            <td>\
                                <div class="fc-title">' + e.title + '</div>\
                                <div class="fc-description">' + e.location + '</div>\
                            </td>\
                        </tr>');
                        tbody.append(segEl);

                        //Tried to use fullcalendar code for this stuff but to no avail
                        (function(_this, myEvent, mySegEl) { //temp bug fix because 'e' seems to change
                            segEl.on('click', function(ev) {
                                return _this.trigger('eventClick', mySegEl, myEvent, ev);
                            });
                        })(this, e, segEl);

                    }

                }

                currentDayStart.add(1, 'days');
            }

            this.updateHeight();

            View.prototype.renderEvents.apply(this, arguments);
        },

        destroyEvents: function() {
            // responsible for undoing everything in renderEvents
            View.prototype.destroyEvents.apply(this, arguments);
        },

        renderSelection: function(range) {
            // accepts a {start,end} object made of Moments, and must render the selection
            View.prototype.renderSelection.apply(this, arguments);
        },

        destroySelection: function() {
            // responsible for undoing everything in renderSelection
            View.prototype.destroySelection.apply(this, arguments);
        }

    });

    FC.views.list = ListView; // register our class with the view system

})();
```

---

### For older versions of fullcalendar

I made something like what you're talking about:
https://github.com/samedii/fullcalendar

Just set
basicListInterval: { 'days': 30 }

The view is called 'basicList'

Edit (more graphic solution):

`src/basic/basicList.js`

```
/* A view with a simple list
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

fcViews.basicList = BasicListView; // register this view

function BasicListView(calendar) {
    BasicView.call(this, calendar); // call the super-constructor
}


BasicListView.prototype = createObject(BasicView.prototype); // define the super-class
$.extend(BasicListView.prototype, {

    name: 'basicList',


    incrementDate: function(date, delta) {
        var out = date.clone().stripTime().add(delta, 'days');
        out = this.skipHiddenDays(out, delta < 0 ? -1 : 1);
        return out;
    },


    render: function(date) {

        this.intervalStart = date.clone().stripTime();
        this.intervalEnd = this.intervalStart.clone().add(30, 'days');

        this.start = this.skipHiddenDays(this.intervalStart);
        this.end = this.skipHiddenDays(this.intervalEnd, -1, true);
        
        this.title = this.calendar.formatRange(
            this.start,
            this.end.clone().subtract(1), // make inclusive by subtracting 1 ms
            this.opt('titleFormat'),
            ' \u2014 ' // emphasized dash
        );

        BasicView.prototype.render.call(this, 30, 1, true); // call the super-method
    }

});
```

I think you need to run `npm install && bower install` and then `grunt dev` to build.

Comment: Thank's but i need a graphic view. it's to show a lot of event (0~30) on each day. It's why i try to make a view with all the day of a month in column like "basicWeek for a month"

Comment: @Mike what do you mean by "graphic" view?

Comment: A view like basicWeek with all day of the month in column (with just 1 row for all days)

Comment: That's quite easy to do with the original code. I did it before. Try checking out the commit  93dc74ebf92157dc1ace89b55f536ae9b64eb9c7 or the one after

Comment: @Mike Hope that gives you something to start with. I think the list view is more useful

Comment: @Mike If you want to show ~30 events on a single day I don't think the basicWeek approach is a good idea

Comment: Good, i have just change the last line to have all days in one row (instead of all days in one column) and some changes on the date range. But the events are display strangely. Now, i try to search to find why.